# All diagonals of the regular 30-gons are drawn interior. How many distinct point in the interior of the 30-gon do two or more diagonal interesect?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

All diagonals of the regular 30-gons are drawn interior. How many distinct point in the interior of the 30-gon do two or more diagonal interesect?

So how do we generalize a formula for any gons?

This link should help:

http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ngon.pdf

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A006561](https://oeis.org/A006561). Note $6561=3^8$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of pairs of diagonals that intersect is $\binom {30}4$, or $\binom{n}4$ in the case of the general $n$-gon. This is an upper bound for the number of intersections, but it might count some interesections more than once - for example, when $n$ is even, it will count the center $\binom{n/2}2$ times.

The [OEIS link provided by joriki](https://oeis.org/A006561) indicates that no overcounting occurs when $n$ is odd, but the formula for when $n$ is even appears much trickier. That page indicates you need to count the number of $3$-crossing, $4$-crossings, etc, which is obvious, but it doesn't tell you how to do the counting.

The OEIS page gives the number for the $30$-gon as $16801$, which is considerably less than $\binom{30}4=27405$.